# Getting Microsoft Virtual PC to Work on Linux

Tags: linux, internet-explorer, virtualbox, qemu

Has anyone tried to get Windows 7/8 running on linux with the Microsoft Virtual PC download directly from Microsoft?  It doesn't seem to be working using the default Boxes or Virtual Machine (QEMU) in CentOS / Red Hat?

```
SETTINGS:
Base Memory 1024 MB
Video Memory 128 MB
Network Adapter: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (NAT)
Windows Virtual Box (from Microsoft)
```

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575
forward to http://dev.modern.ie/

Is there any chance Microsoft or modern.ie will just release an iso install rather then a native Virtual System File?

Comment: Do you have more information than "It just doesn't work?"

Comment: I tested the downloaded files from Microsoft for windows XP and one for windows 7 and both of them will not run.  The XP version looks for network drivers and the Windows 7 version seems to keep restarting.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to get Microsoft's IE Virtual PC *images* working in VirtualBox (not Virtual PC itself).

Luckily there is a tool available to automate the process of converting the images and getting them to work in VirtualBox. Take a look at [ievms](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms).

Comment: Microsoft now releases VirtualBox images directly; there's no need to convert them. See http://www.modern.ie/.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

This images are legal as `modern.ie` launched by Microsoft.

Site provide a wide range of up-today Windows images for Windows/Mac/Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Virtual PC downloads from http://dev.modern.ie/ (MS) only support Virtual Box on linux and not the Virtual Machine Manager that comes with CentOS.

Comment: The other problem is that Microsoft only gives you a few days to use their virtual PC... even if it did work.